# How to Enable the "Find" option in Chrome Resources Tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

It used to be that I could open Chrome's Developer Tools, navigate to the Resources tab, press ctrl+f and search ALL the resources for a specific string. However, very recently this option seems to be disabled. This is a feature that I use all of the time.

Is anyone else experiencing this? And more importantly, how can I fix it to enable the find option again?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I select the html tag and hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> then I can find what I want in the dev tools window.